# React only on specific rhandsontable column change

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have a plot that depends only on a specific column of a bigger rhandsontable. I want to trigger the reactiveness of the plot only if that column changes. Every solution I've tried cause the rerendering of the plot even if I change other columns. Is there a way to do this?

Here's a minimal example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("chart"),
  rHandsontableOutput("hot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  DF <- data.frame(
    x1 = 1,
    x2 = 2,
    x3 = 3, # I want to rerender the chart only if this column changes
    stringsAsFactors = F
  )

  output$hot = renderRHandsontable({ 
    rhandsontable(DF)  
  })

  output$chart = renderPlot({
    print("change!")
    hist(hot_to_r(input$hot)$x3, col = 'skyblue3')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution via `observeEvent` and `reactiveVal`:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("chart"),
  rHandsontableOutput("hot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  DF <- data.frame(
    x1 = 1,
    x2 = 2,
    x3 = 3, # I want to rerender the chart only if this column changes
    stringsAsFactors = F
  )

  output$hot = renderRHandsontable({ 
    rhandsontable(DF)  
  })

  x3 <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$hot, {
     x3(hot_to_r(input$hot)$x3)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

  output$chart = renderPlot({
    req({x3()})
    print("change!")
    hist(x3(), col = 'skyblue3')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Exactly what I looking for! Thank you!